# Can you rebuild node_modules on azure linux app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

The node_modules directory has been corrupted on on our azure linux app service - someone accidentally checked it into git and deployment picked it up and hosed a bunch of stuff. The end result now is that during a deploy we get file not found errors referring to node_module files that are not there. Mkdirp is playing up big time for example. Is there anyway to rebuild the node_modules on a linux instance like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, if your package.json doesn't changed. You could locate to the wwwroot and run npm install command to restore the node_modules.

More details, you could refer to this steps:

1.Open the kudu.

[image]

2.Open the bash console.

[image]

3.Locate the wwwroot folder and run the install command command.

```
cd site
cd wwwroot
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks, thats so easy!